# problem when using += in setInterval to continually increment a variable

Tags: javascript, setinterval

here are two questions about the exercise that I am doing for practicing of `setInterval` fuction

1. from following code, I tried to print out the variable which is self-adding by 10 within 1000 milliseconds, but when I ran it, in the console of browser, it only showed 10 times of same word "num", how do I figure it out ?

```js
$(function() {
  var timmer;
  GoCount();

  function GoCount() {
    timmer = setInterval(function() {
      var num = 0;
      num += 10;
      console.log(num);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2. and the second question is what's the difference between `setInterval` and for loop

Comment: Move `var num = 0;` out of the GoCount function, and then it will work just fine.

Comment: 2. `setInterval` iterates at a given delay and is effectively asynchronous. A `for` loop runs synchronously without delay (unless once is manually created). If you're ever in doubt about anything to do with JS, always refer to MDN: [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: This does *not* output *the word "num"*…!

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen , it works !  many thanks !

Answer (score 3):

As @Carsten Løvbo Andersen 's comment, you should make the `num` as global variable to be able to keep the previous value.

```js
$(function() {
  var timmer;
  var num = 0;
  GoCount();

  function GoCount() {
    timmer = setInterval(function() {
      num += 10;
      console.log(num);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `num` isn't a global above (which is good!). Can also get rid of the OP's `timmer` variable...

Comment: I totally agree with you, it should be param passing `GoCount(startNumber);` instead.

Comment: I'm just saying, you've called it a global. It isn't one. (And yes, that would make sense.)

Answer (score 1):

Each time you the function runs you set "num" back to zero and add 10. You need to declare the num as 0 outside of that function, in the same place as "timmer".

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your variable as function params then you can change the start number as well.

```js
$(function() {
  var timmer;
  GoCount(0);

  function GoCount(num) {
    timmer = setInterval(function() {
     
      num += 10;
      console.log(num);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

codes inside a loop will be run without delay, but in setInterval you can set that how much time should be between running the codes in your scope.

Answer (score 1):

Create the `num` variable outside the `setInterval` function. In your code the `num` variable is declare as new variable and assigned the value to `0` each time the `setInterval` executes.

```js
$(function() {
    var timmer;
    GoCount();

    function GoCount() {
        var num = 0;
        timmer = setInterval(function() {
            num += 10;
            console.log(num);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code simpler by creating an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) like this:

```js
((num) => setInterval(() => {
  num += 10
  console.log(num)
}, 1000))(0) // <- Initialize the `num` variable here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the num by 10 with each iteration you need to move out the num variable (as  @Carsten Løvbo Andersen said):

```js
$(function() {
  var num = 0;
  var timmer;
  GoCount();

  function GoCount() {
    timmer = setInterval(function() {
      num += 10;
      console.log(num);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/f8hn4xrw/ for a working example

Comment: Why fiddle. The `[<>]` stacksnippet works just fine here

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Just a personal preference